# Are up votes moderated

Tags: discussion, voting

I don't understand the up voting system (I do I'm just point making). If you hover over the up vote icon it states, and I quote:

"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"

Yet questions like this [Using HTML as a interface for VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776555/using-html-as-a-interface-for-vba-excel) , show no research, and are not helpful (nor that clear).

I don't particularly want to flag the question as the user clearly needs help, but my question is who reads that and thinks is deserves upvoting?!

Hypothetical questions aside, are up votes (or down votes) moderated and removed as and where necessary, or left there to give other users the misguided impression a question might be helpful and clear?

Comment: this is a community site. The intent is that even if some people vote poorly (either way), the larger community vote will rectify the situation. Don't downvote to ADJUST a score ("oh this post is bad, but not bad enough for -3, I'll give an upvote"), but do vote based on the quality of the post (this is good = up. this is bad = down).

Comment: SO users do tend to consider a question useful when they'd like to see an answer as well.  Surely most anybody that uses UserForms in VBA now would find the prospect attractive :)  Research was done too, he's certainly not going to google that.  It is clear.

Comment: *questions like this show no research, and are not helpful (nor that clear)...I don't particularly want to flag the question* - I am very confused.

Comment: Confused by what? The OP states they have googled yet any google along the lines of their question reveals many answers, or at least starting points. I guess then my query is less so with the quality of questions, but whether the community agree with the description of the up vote?

Comment: Feel free to vote to adjust the score. Everybody does, and it's your vote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah - by you. If you see a question that's not useful or clear, downvote it. It's free.

Comment: Doesn't downvoting cost reputation for non-meta sites?

Comment: @star2wars3: Only on answers.

Comment: Well yes of course, however my concerns are that for every up vote, a down vote has to be cast to keep the score level. The topic I referred to currently shows a down vote of -4, meaning 6 people have had to down vote. The masses indicate it is not a useful questions, yet 2 votes had to be lost by the 2 that up voted.

Comment: That's the purpose of voting, @tim - to gather the *collective* opinion of folks on the site. The score reflects the results of all voter's opinions.